# Factorizing classical Eisenstein series

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, eisenstein-series

In the course of my research, I found some surprising (for me) factorizations
of Eisenstein series in levels $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$. For instance, in level $1$
set with standard modular form notation
$$G_{\pm}(\tau)=2E_2(\tau)-((3\pm\sqrt{-3})/6)E_2(\tau/2)-((3\mp\sqrt{-3})/6) E_2((\tau+1)/2)$$
Then, among other properties we have $G_{\pm}^3=E_6\pm\sqrt{-1728\Delta}$ but especially
the factorization
$$E_4=G_{+}G_{-}$$
Similar formulas occur in levels $2$, $3$, and $4$, and in level $4$ an additional amusing
thing happens: set (with $\theta=\sum_{n\in{\mathbb Z}}q^{n^2}$)
$$G_{\pm}(\tau)=\theta(2\tau)\pm(\sqrt{-1}/2)(\theta(\tau/2)-\theta((\tau+1)/2)$$
Then $G_{\pm}^4$ is again an explicit modular form of weight $2$, but more amusingly we have
$$\theta^2=G_{+}G_{-}$$
so a modular form of weight $1$ equal in two different ways as the product of two modular
forms of weight $1/2$. I realize that this is a possibility, but surprising nonetheless.
In passing note that $\theta$ is an eta quotient, but the $G_{\pm}$ are only "twisted" eta quotients, in a suitable sense.

> **Question 1.** Since all this is so elementary, it must be well-known. Is there a reference?

> **Question 2.** What is really going on? I have a non illuminating proof of all the identities by checking enough coefficients in
> finite-dimensional vector spaces of modular forms, but this is not
> satisfactory.

Comment: There is a problem in $\theta^2=G_{+}G_{-}$. You don't like the idea that those kind of identifies appear because spaces of modular forms are finite dimensional? Ramanujan may have some direct series manipulation techniques for proving some of those, but I doubt it generalizes well.